# Vector of objects containing references or pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I store some objects in a vector. When I call a member function of such an object that uses a reference the program gets terminated (no error). I wrote the following code do run some tests. It seams like after adding elements, the reference in the first entry fails. Why is that and what can I do to avoid this issue? It's exactly the same behaviour when I use pointers instead of references.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(int i) : var(i), ref(var) {}
    int get_var() {return var;}
    int get_ref() {return ref;}
private:
    int var;
    int& ref;
};

int main ()
{
    vector<A> v;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<=2 ;i++){
        v.emplace_back(i+5);
        cout<<"entry "<<i<<":"<<endl;
        cout<<"  var="<<v.at(i).get_var()<<endl;
        cout<<"  ref="<<v.at(i).get_ref()<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<=2 ;i++){
        cout<<"entry "<<i<<":"<<endl;
        cout<<"  var="<<v.at(i).get_var()<<endl;
        cout<<"  ref="<<v.at(i).get_ref()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
entry 0:
  var=5
  ref=5
entry 1:
  var=6
  ref=6
entry 2:
  var=7
  ref=7

entry 0:
  var=5
  ref=0          /////////////here it happens!
entry 1:
  var=6
  ref=6
entry 2:
  var=7
  ref=7
v has 3 entries
```

Comment: Which compiler and version is being used?  The use of `at` may also be causing problems, depending on which compiler.  I have been unsuccessful finding the posts that discuss the compiler having a problem with `at`.  If in doubt, use the `[]` operator instead.  In this case it would look like `v[i].get_var()` and `v[i].get_ref()`.

Comment: @Edward why did you add the C++11 tag?  Was the C++ tag not sufficient - is there anything specific to c++11 about this?

Comment: Hi, i use gcc 4.8.1. The use uf `[]` makes no difference.

Comment: Good to see that the 4.8.1 compiler is used.  It should be recent enough that the `at` quirks are gone.

Comment: @Tom, `emplace_back` is C++11-only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your calls to emplace_back are causing the vector to resize.  In order to do this, the vector may or may not have to move the entire vector to a different place in memory.  Your "ref" is still referencing the old memory location.

Whether or not this actually happens is somewhat implementation dependent; compilers are free to reserve extra memory for the vector so they don't have to reallocate every single time you add something to the back.

It's mentioned in the standard documentation for [emplace_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/):

> **Iterator validity**
>
> If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers
>   and references related to this container are invalidated. Otherwise,
>   only the end iterator is invalidated, and all other iterators,
>   pointers and references to elements are guaranteed to keep referring
>   to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

To avoid the problem you could either (as JAB suggested in the comments) create the reference on the fly instead of storing it as a member variable:

```
int& get_ref() {return var;}
```

... although I would much rather use a smart pointer instead of this sort of thing.

Or, as RnMss suggested, implement the copy constructor so that it references the new location whenever the object is copied by vector:

```
A(A const& other) : ref(var) {
    *this = other;
}
```

Comment: So dani would be better off using something like `int& get_ref() {return var;}`, then? (Or would it be better as `const int&`? I can never remember the conventions for returning references to member variables, though without the `const` things like `v.at(i).get_ref() = 3` become possible.)

Comment: the excerpt about iterator validity is about validity of references to elements of vector. ref is reference to member of class

Comment: @JAB Yes your suggestion of `int& get_ref() {return var;}` would work better.  Returning references to member variables is always a little scary though; if I have to do it I would rather use smart pointers.

Comment: What matters is not `emplace_back` or `get_ref()`. It's that when reallocation happens, the default copy-constructor is called, doesn't initialize the `ref` the way you expect, it actually copys the address of the old object's `var`. Implementing a explicit copy/move constructor would fix this.

Comment: @lizusek I disagree.  "If a reallocation happens all ... references related to this container are invalidated".  `ref` in his example is a reference related to the container because it references a struct member inside the container.

Comment: using your argument vector<int>& ref is also invalidated as related to vector (isn't it?). IMO "related to this container" means "to elements" as is said explicitly in second sentence

Comment: @JAB Generally speaking, a get method returning a copy of private data is better.  The next best thing is to return an `int&` from the data variable (e.g. `var`), and not ever use a separate internal reference variable.  The separate internal reference variable can easily not refer to the correct data member, when there is no copy constructor and/or a deep copy does not occur.  It is also safer to assume that the default copy constructor will never behave as needed, and an explicit one has to be implemented for an element stored in a container.

Comment: @lizusek Yeah, I think by "related to this container" they mean the underlying container, not the std::vector object itself.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD True enough, though if the data member in question is very large there could be potential use in returning a const reference to the object (in a case where for whatever reason the compiler wouldn't use copy elision to achieve a similar effect [given the return type is still const], at least).

Comment: @JAB Yes, I agree.  It is always a good thing to understand the requirements and implement accordingly.

Comment: IMO ref is not related to container. It is a ref to class member. It is just coincidence that in this scenario it is "related" to the container, because somebody will copy objects wrong way, because of lack appropriate copy constructor. If there was no copying this would work. It would also work if there was copying but with correct constructor, however real references related to container are invalidated. So you see ref in this class has nothing to do with notion of relation to container. Not invalidation of vector references but lack of correct copy ctor is real problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so here is what's happening.  It really helps to understand your objects in terms of memory location, and remember that vector is allowed to move objects around in memory.

`v.emplace_back(5)`

You create an A-object in the vector.  This object now resides in a block of memory ranging from `0x1234` to `0x123C`.  Member variable **var** sits at `0x1234` and member variable **ref** sits at `0x1238`.  For this object, the value of **var** is `0x0005` and the value of **ref** is `0x1234`.

While adding elements to the vector, the vector runs out of space during the second insert.  So, it resizes and moves the current elements (which at this moment is just the first element) from location `0x1234` to location `0x2000`.  This means the member elements also moved, so **var** is now located at address `0x2000` and **ref** is now located at `0x2004`.  But their values were copied, so the value of **var** is still `0x0005` and the value of **ref** is still `0x1234`.

**ref** is pointing at an invalid location (but **var** still contains the right value!).  Trying to access the memory **ref** now points to undefined behavior and generally bad.

Something like this would be a much more typical approach to providing reference access to a member attribute:

```
int & get_ref() {return var;}
```

Having references as member attributes isn't *wrong* in and of itself, but if you are storing a reference to an object, you have to make sure that that object doesn't move.